# Trouble shooting Google-managed SSL Certificate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

On Sunday, 13 June, I went through all the steps to add in a Google-managed SSL certificate and when I finished the Load Balancing result was 'Provisional'. The domain status is 'Failed_Not_Visible'. When I went to troubleshoot "To resolve this issue, update the DNS records to point to your load balancer's IP address" and I don't know the IP address. In fact, when I went to add in a new record in the DNS and played around with a few different IPs, I crashed my website. I deleted the DNS record I created as per the GCP documentation, the website did not return. I have double-checked everything and cannot see where the error is. My website is still down.

Comment: When you created the load balancer frontend, you assigned a global public IP address. That IP address is the value for the DNS resource record. Once you create the resource record you must wait for the load balancer to check again.

Comment: Thanks so much John. I have just added an A record to the Cloud DNS with the IP: 34.102.147.193. However, I now have 2 A records. One with the IP from the Load Balancing and one from the VM instance (Compute Engine: 35.239.145.25). I'm guessing I should delete the A record with the IP from the VM instance?

Comment: Yes, delete the A record pointing to the VM.

Comment: John, it did not fix the issue. I'm now in the process of trying to find someone to pay to fix it. I have a small budget but would a job like this interest you?

Comment: You can contact me via my website https://www.jhanley.com